# How do I generate an IO Vector?

Tags: haskell, vector

[`Data.Vector` has `generate :: Int -> (Int -> a) -> Vector a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector.html#g:7) but I don't see an equivalent in `Data.Vector.Mutable`.  What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like it just doesn’t exist, but if you don’t mind the copy, you can just `thaw` a regular `generate`d or `generateM`’d vector.

Comment: The `Mutable` modules are the “imperative” interfaces to the vector library. The idea is kind of, _only use these modules when you want exact control over every single memory-access operation_.

In that light, the preferred mutable solution would be to _not initialize the array at all_, instead use the function the first time you actually do something mutable with the array entries.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I don't understand. It seems to me that `Data.Vector.Mutable` is for *mutable* vectors (in `IO` or `ST`).  It's not an interface to the immutable data structure in `Data.Vector`.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely apply `unsafeThaw` to the output of `generate` to produce a mutable vector with zero copying:

```
import Data.Vector
import Data.Vector.Mutable
main :: IO ()
main = do mv <- unsafeThaw (generate 10 (*5))
          write mv 3 999
          print =<< freeze mv
```

Note that the only thing that makes `unsafeThaw` unsafe is that you cannot use the immutable vector after the operation, so the pattern above *is* safe.

Comment: Any idea why the library author didn't just include a version of `generate` for mutable vectors?

Comment: No, I don't, but you could open an issue at the package [bug tracker](https://github.com/haskell/vector/issues) and ask.  Everyone there seems pretty responsive.

Comment: OK, I've done that.  Thanks for the suggestion. https://github.com/haskell/vector/issues/175